# Router wifi connection problem

Tags: wireless, router

I have a router ZTE H218N. It work OK on LAN, but I'm unable to connect my HP on wireless.
Another HP on my desk, with Win, Wi Fi works perfect.

Could somebody help me with some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just installed *Wicd Network Manager* and the problem is solved.